# help loading Ubuntu along side Windows xp

Tags: system-installation

I am a newbie. How do I get started?  I have Windows xp, and would like to run Ubuntu as well. I have downloaded Ubuntu to a memory stick, to a DVD-RW, and to 'Programs' on 'My Computer'.  It downloads to 'My Computer' as "pagefiles.sys'.  When I try to open from any source, I get the message:

```
This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action.
Crate an association in Folder Options control panel.
```

None of the options offered allow me to open Ubuntu.
How do I get it to operate as my operating system?  What do I do?  I do not understand many of the term I see used in the Q & A sections.

Answer (score 1):

Boot to the Linux DVD that you burned and follow the installation prompt.  Choose the option to install along side Windows.  Continue to follow the prompt.

The installation is very automatic.  When the installation is complete and you reboot the computer you'll see an option to either boot into Windows or boot into Linux.

By the way the "pagefiles.sys" file is a windows component that has nothing to do with Linux.  None of the other steps that you mention has any thing to do with the actual installation.  You'll have to boot to the disk to perform the installation.

By the way, that is the same way you install Windows.  You boot to the installation disk.

Comment: Thanks, but I guess the real question is, then, how do I boot to the Umbutu?

Comment: being a neophyte I have never knowingly 'booted' anything. Windows has always been on the computers that I have purchased, and I have never had to boot it.

Comment: The boot menu should come up automatically and give you the option to boot Ubuntu or Windows XP.

Comment: User267196 the answer to your new question is in the first answer.  Look at the second of the four paragraphs.  I believe this is a case of easier done than said.  Just boot to the DVD answer the simple questions and when you restart the computer you'll have an option to boot to Windows or Linux (just as saiarcot895 said.  You may be surprise at the ease that is built into Ubuntu.  Being a neophyte shouldn't be too much of a hindrance.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to do a dual boot and that Windows XP is already installed.

I'll try to explain it in the simplest way :

1. Download Ubuntu from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop . Make sure to choose 32-bit.
2. Download and install lili usb creator from http://www.linuxliveusb.com/fr/home .
3. Plug your usb key.
4. Launch lili usb creator. Select your usb key, select the iso you downloaded at step 1, click on the lightning. Now you have a bootable usb key.
5. Now you must boot from usb key. Turn on your computer, press on esc and F2 (one of the two keys should start an ugly screen like this http://asri-education.org/sites/default/files/images/images_redacteurs/00_pour_tous/revalorisation/bios_phoenix_01.png, if not restart and try another keys [There is a chance your computer shows them at the bottom of the very first screen you'll see]). Go to Boot, Search for a name that should be your USB key, using / or +/- (the commands are specified on the right), bring your USB key at the top of the choices. Now go to exit and select save and exit. Your computer should restart on Ubuntu.
6. When prompter, choose install ubuntu. Then choose install ubuntu alongside Windows

I hope you'll be able to follow these directives. Don't mind to ask further details. If your computer is very old, the installation won't work. If so, try to find and older ubuntu version and follow the same instructions.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try it. What is meant by 'plug your usb key', and 'bootable usb key'?

Comment: Plug the usb key in the computer.
It means you can boot on your usb key. Currently, your computer boots Windows XP from your hard drive but if you configured an usb key as above, you can boot ubuntu from your usb key (We could say Ubuntu is installed on the usb key).